# Neo4j: Why can`t I find a particular node by find_one in python?

Tags: python, neo4j

I am new to use Neo4j in python2.7. Now I have tried an easy test about Neo4j, but I can`t find the particular node in the database. The Node is existed, but the return result is 'None'. 
Here are my codes:

```
from py2neo import Graph,Node,Relationship
test_graph = Graph(
    "http://localhost:7474", 
    username="neo4j", 
    password="******"
)
test_node_1 = Node(label = "Person",name = "test_node_1")
test_node_2 = Node(label = "Person",name = "test_node_2")
test_graph.create(test_node_1)
test_graph.create(test_node_2)

node_1_call_node_2 = Relationship(test_node_1,'CALL',test_node_2)
node_2_call_node_1 = Relationship(test_node_2,'CALL',test_node_1)
test_graph.create(node_1_call_node_2)
test_graph.create(node_2_call_node_1)

find_code_1 = test_graph.find_one(
  label="Person",
  property_key="name",
  property_value="test_node_1"
)
print (find_code_1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your syntax for the Node is slightly off. You're setting a property called label with the value Person, you're not creating Person nodes.

Here's what the syntax should be like :

```
test_node_1 = Node("Person",name = "test_node_1")
test_node_2 = Node("Person",name = "test_node_2")
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom